# jquery mobile dynamically inserting new links into the DOM not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm still new to jQuery mobile. I'm trying to fix a minor problem on one of my pages.

I have a page that has a simple list of links. There's nothing special here, just this:

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="test.php">One</a></li>
    <li> <a href="test1.php">Two</a></li>
    <li> <a href="test2.php">Three</a></li>
    <li> <a href="test3.php">Four</a></li>
    <li> <a href="test4.php">Five</a></li>
<ul>    
<a href="#" id="list_more">More</a>
```

I have a bit of js so that when the `#list_more` link is clicked, we do an ajax call that pulls the next five items and adds to the end of the `ul`.

```
$('#list_more').click(function(){
    $.post("/scripts/ajax.php", function(data){
        $('#list_more').attr('data-time',data.time);
        $('ul li:last').after(data.out);
    });
})
```

The pages are setup using multipage templates. Because the new pages are being added to the DOM dynamically, I'm getting an `Error loading page` message. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: For first, you forget `return false` before exit function. And where do you get this error?

Comment: added the `return false` but it hasn't made any difference I can tell. The error comes up when I click on any of the newly added links.

Comment: are you sure that data.out has good links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried refreshing your list? http://operationmobile.com/dont-forget-to-call-refresh-when-adding-items-to-your-jquery-mobile-list/